# Выбрать строки в лог файле в зависимости от времени

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

dateminusten=$(date -d "10 minutes ago" +"%F %T")

declare -a arr=("2018-04-28 06:24:28,450 Log message 2wecewcewcewcewce" "2018-04-28 06:26:28,440 Log message 3wecewcewcew" "2018-04-28 06:28:28,640 log message 5c ewcwewc" "2018-04-28 06:30:28,220 log message 6" "2018-04-28 06:31:28,650 log message 4" "2018-04-28 06:32:28,634 log message 5" "2018-04-28 06:36:28,650 very long messageewcewcec" "2018-04-28 06:37:28,420 ewcewcewcewcwe wecewcwew" "2018-04-28 06:38:28,120 cwewwecewcewcwecwewecwe")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
done
```

Нужно выбрать строки, время в которых меньше в пределах 10 минут от текущего времени. Текущее время для этого примера 2018-04-28 06:40:28

Получаю это время так: `dateminusten=$(date -d "10 minutes ago" +"%F %T")`
и формируется строка вида `2018-04-28 06:30:28`

Как выбрать строки время в которых находится между `2018-04-28 06:30:28` и `2018-04-28 06:40:28` ?

Разбивать строку по пробелам на подстроки, объединять первые две подстроки и потом как-то сравнивать дату. Вот что приходит на ум. Но тогда что делать с тысячными секунды?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даты в квази-iso'шном формате да ещё когда они в начале строки удобны тем, что их можно сравнивать лексикографически без всякой подготовки. Например так:

```
$ cat file
2018-04-28 06:24:28,450 Log message 2wecewcewcewcewce
2018-04-28 06:26:28,440 Log message 3wecewcewcew
2018-04-28 06:28:28,640 log message 5c ewcwewc
2018-04-28 06:30:28,220 log message 6
2018-04-28 06:31:28,650 log message 4
2018-04-28 06:32:28,634 log message 5
2018-04-28 06:36:28,650 very long messageewcewcec
2018-04-28 06:37:28,420 ewcewcewcewcwe wecewcwew
2018-04-28 06:38:28,120 cwewwecewcewcwecwewecwe
$ datestart="$(date -d "2018-04-28 06:30:28" +"%F %T")"
$ dateend="$(date -d "2018-04-28 06:40:28" +"%F %T")"
$ awk "{if(\"$datestart\"<\$0 && \$0<\"$dateend\") print \$0}" file
2018-04-28 06:30:28,220 log message 6
2018-04-28 06:31:28,650 log message 4
2018-04-28 06:32:28,634 log message 5
2018-04-28 06:36:28,650 very long messageewcewcec
2018-04-28 06:37:28,420 ewcewcewcewcwe wecewcwew
2018-04-28 06:38:28,120 cwewwecewcewcwecwewecwe
```

Comment: без awk? for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
  if [[ "$datestart"<$i && $i<"$dateend" ]] then echo $i fi
done не работает

Comment: @GarfieldCat, УМВР: https://paste.pound-python.org/show/1j2UBVxPNbdJVr36Iha8/